# getline() takes line ending and next line beginning

Tags: c++, getline

I have a problem with one of my tasks. I have an Excel file which looks like this:

[image: File I take information from]

The problem is that `getline()` takes strings until it finds `','` but at the end of the line there is no `','`. There is so much data I can't put them everywhere.

My question is, how can I put `','` at line endings with my code?

Here is my code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void names(string value);
void names1(string value);
int main()
{
    ifstream file ("15mil.csv"); // declare file stream: 
    string value;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        getline (file, value, ',');
        names(value);
    }

}

void names(string value) {
    if(value.find('.') != std::string::npos) {
        cout << "float: " << value << endl;
    }
    if(value.find('/') != std::string::npos) {
        cout << "data: " << value << endl;
    }
    if(value.length() == 1) {
        cout << "char: " << value << endl;
    }

    if(value.length() > 1) {
        if(value.find('1') == std::string::npos && value.find('2') == std::string::npos && value.find('3') == std::string::npos && value.find('4') == std::string::npos && value.find('5') == std::string::npos && value.find('6') == std::string::npos && value.find('7') == std::string::npos && value.find('8') == std::string::npos && value.find('9') == std::string::npos && value.find('0') == std::string::npos) {
            cout << "string: " << value << endl;
        }

        else if(value.find('.') == std::string::npos && value.find('/') == std::string::npos && value.length() != 1) {
            cout << "int: " << value << endl;
        }
    }

    if(value.length() > 1 && value.find('S') != std::string::npos) {
        cout << "string: " << value << endl;
    }


}


void names1(string value) {
    if(value.length() > 1) {
        if(value.find('1') == std::string::npos && value.find('2') == std::string::npos && value.find('3') == std::string::npos && value.find('4') == std::string::npos && value.find('5') == std::string::npos && value.find('6') == std::string::npos && value.find('7') == std::string::npos && value.find('8') == std::string::npos && value.find('9') == std::string::npos && value.find('0') == std::string::npos) {
            cout << "string: " << value << endl;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `std::getline()` with default `'\n'` delimiter to read an entire line from the file into a `std::string`, then create a `std::istringstream` for that string and use `std::getline()` with `','` delimiter to read comma-separated values from it, and process them as needed. Repeat for each line in the file as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add it at the and after getline, with a help of `value += ',';` Or `value.push_back(',');`, right here:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    getline (file, value, ',');

    value += ','; // Or value.push_back(',');
    names(value);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, that where is ',' after every string, however there is no ',' on the line ending. So last string always being float with string infused.

Comment: @PovilasKamarauskas If you want to move on the next line your output after end of the string then add `value += ",\n";` . This will add `,` at the end and symbol of new line `\n`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Look at my file I added on the sixth line ending you can find 62217.18
 and seventh line begining there is asia. The problem when I group strings 62217.18 goes to 'float:" but asia aswell even tho it is in entirely other line. The string float: 62217.18 Asia. And I need to be Float : 62217.18    String: Asia.

Comment: @PovilasKamarauskas add some lines from your csv, can't understand problem

Comment: There is file photo in description